# Word vba Documents.open with URL makes request three times

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a vba makro which opens a document with a url from a server.
The script looks like this:

```
Documents.Open("http://restservice/doc/" + TextBox1.value, True, False)
```

Everything works fine. I get my document. But looking through the logs of the restservice I found out that everytime Documents.Open was called once it made the excact same request to the given URL three times. Why does it do this and how can I prevent it. The restservice has to do a search in an archive to deliver the file. This comes at a certain cost.
I'm using Word 10.

Comment: Is [this known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019105) possibly related?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Office uses WebDAV protocol for manipulating online contents. For this purpose it requires to negotiate to server for discovering available methods, or locking the document or saving it and etc...

If WebDAV methods have been not provided by your server, ( that it seems that it is your case ). Don't worry it is just checking it.

If they had been provided by server, word could save the document directly to server. Otherwise it will ask for the location to save.